# "j_spring_security_check" not found after configuring spring security directly without http auto config

Tags: spring

I’m trying to convert Spring Security configuration from HTTP namespace into direct configuration using FilterChainProxy. Before the conversion, everything was ok with HTTP namespace. But after replacing  element by several elements with FilterChainProxy, I got “j_spring_security_check not found” error while login to the system. I tried to change all or some of “/j_spring_security_check” with “/app/j_spring_security_check” but still could not login successfully.

My environment:
  AppFuse 2.1 with Spring MVC, iBatis, Spring Security 3.0.7, tuckey urlrewrite 3.2.0, Spring 3.0.6
  Windows 7 
  JDK 1.5.0_17 
  Maven 2.2.1
  apache-tomcat-6.0.32

**Security.xml (before conversion, everything is OK.)**

```
…
<http auto-config="true" lowercase-comparisons="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
…
```

**Security.xml (after replacing http namespace, "j_spring_security_check" not found)**

```
<beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/styles/**" filters="none"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/app/**" filters="
             securityContextPersistenceFilter,
             authenticationProcessingFilter,
             exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor"/>
    </filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/mainMenu"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/403.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <filter-security-metadata-source>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        </filter-security-metadata-source>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"
            class="com.tangram.ebiz.webapp.authentication.MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource">
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**Login.jsp**

```
    <form method="post" id="loginForm" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" onsubmit="saveUsername(this);return validateForm(this)">
…
        <li>
            <label for="j_username" class="required desc"><fmt:message key="label.username"/> <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="text medium" name="j_username" id="j_username" tabindex="1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="j_password" class="required desc"><fmt:message key="label.password"/> <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" class="text medium" name="j_password" id="j_password" tabindex="2" />
        </li>
…
    </form>
```

**Urlrewrite.xml**

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
…
<!-- Add rules here for anything that shouldn't be served up by Spring MVC. -->
<rule>
    <from>/</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true">mainMenu</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>/app/**</from>
    <to last="true" type="redirect">%{context-path}/$1</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>/j_spring_security_check**</from>
    <to last="true">/j_spring_security_check$1</to>
</rule>
…

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<rule>
    <from>/**</from>
    <to>/app/$1</to>
</rule>
<outbound-rule>
    <from>/app/**</from>
    <to>/$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
…
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: My environment: 
AppFuse 2.1 with Spring MVC, iBatis, Spring Security 3.0.7, tuckey urlrewrite 3.2.0, Spring 3.0.6 
Windows 7 
JDK 1.5.0_17 
Maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I fixed it myself.

While debugging the doFilter() method of SecurityContextPersistenceFilter without Spring security namespace, I found that contextBeforeChainExecution and contextAfterChainExecution were null. But when debugging the program with namespace the value of both of them were something about Anonymous.

I added “/j_spring_security_check” and “/login” with “IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY” access in securityMetadataSource as shown below and the problem was solved.

```
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <filter-security-metadata-source>
            <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        </filter-security-metadata-source>
    </beans:property>
```

This blog really helped me a lot: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/